# bootstrap full width. div is taking less space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="container-fluid top">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of typ
        </p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

i have given col-lg-12 to a div, but on giving position: fixed why it is taking least size. why still i need to give width:100 percentage to div.

Comment: You have your markup in the wrong order for one, start with `container-fluid' (**container / row / column**), see the [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro)

Answer (score 1):

Your correct architecture (not always, but most of the time) is:

container - row - col

So in this case it would be something like this:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of typ
         </p>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Now, if the text doesn't go all the way to the edge is because col-lg-* classes have a gutter padding of 15px. Simply remove the col-lg-* class and you will have the row instead which it doesn't have a padding.

See my [**demo here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVRbxq?editors=110)

**EDIT**

Credit to [Tim Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965631/tim-lewis):

"the container and container-fluid both have a 15px margin and row has a -15px margin. Make sure to not wind up with a -15px or 30px margin, depending on how you use them"

Comment: duly noted :) I'll add that to the answer - you've been credited @TimLewis

Comment: ok.. now i edited my code like this..
<div class="container-fluid top">
<div class="row">

  
  <p class="logo">loonybird.in</p>

  
    

</div>
</div>
now, i have given black as a background color to my top class, but black is coming only in the background of text. not in the full width.
why ??

Answer (score 1):

A simple Bootstrap architecture like

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

You can see more on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be corrected as

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```